# Do we need a facebook app per like button to fully utilise all features

Tags: facebook

Do I need to create a new facebook app for every like button on my site in order to fully utilise every functionality of the like button i.e. insights etc.  Or, can I have one app for my domain and use multiple like buttons on different pages.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can use all the features of the like button by having a single app for all the like buttons on your domain. It would be a disaster to have to create an app for each button as many sights have 1000s of buttons. You will be able to see insights, publish, etc. by using the same app for each button.